# How do I get sequelize to not use timestamp fields when generating SQL for getting n:m associated models?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, postgresql-11

My models:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Vendor = sequelize.define('Vendor', {
        id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        // other fields
    }, {});
    Vendor.associate = function (models) {
        Vendor.belongsToMany(models.Corporate, { through: 'VendorCorporates', foreignKey: 'vendorId' });
    };
    return Vendor;
};
```

and

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Corporate = sequelize.define('Corporate', {
        id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        // other fields
    }, {});
    Corporate.associate = function (models) {
        Corporate.belongsToMany(models.Vendor, { through: 'VendorCorporates', foreignKey: 'corporateId' });
    };
    return Corporate;
};
```

and the migration for the association (link) table:

```
'use strict';

const vendorCorps = 'VendorCorporates', vendorId = 'vendorId', corpId = 'corporateId';

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable(vendorCorps, {
            vendorId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: {
                    model: 'Vendors',
                    key: 'id'
                },
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            },
            corporateId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: {
                    model: 'Corporates',
                    key: 'id'
                },
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            },
            // notice no timestamps
        });
    },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('VendorCorporates');
    }
};
```

Now when I try to get the Corporates that are associated with a Vendor:

```
let vendor = await models.Vendor.findByPk(pk);
let corporates = await vendor.getCorporates();
```

the query fails because sequelize generates SQL with the fields `updatedAt` and `createdAt`. How do I tell sequelize to generate SQL **without** the timestamp fields?

**Clarification:** I want timestamps in the `Corporate` & `Vendor` models, but none in the link/association table, and I want the join query (`vendor.getCorporates()`) to be generated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this by writing a model for the `n:m` association itself:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const VendorCorporate = sequelize.define('VendorCorporate', {
        vendorId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        corporateId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, { timestamps: false });
    VendorCorporate.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
    };
    return VendorCorporate;
};
```

and changing:

```
// db/models/vendor.js

Vendor.belongsToMany(models.Corporate, { through: 'VendorCorporates', foreignKey: 'vendorId' });
```

to:

```
Vendor.belongsToMany(models.Corporate, { through: models.VendorCorporate, foreignKey: 'vendorId' });
```

and making a similar change in the `Corporate` model file.

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate this using the **timestamps** option. For instance:

```
const Corporate = sequelize.define('Corporate', {
        id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        // other fields
    }, {
      timestamps: false
});
```

Comment: That would create no timestamps in the `Corporate` model. I want timestamps in the `Corporate` & `Vendor` models, but none in the link/association table, and I want the join query to be generated accordingly.

Comment: Just indicate timestamps: false in the VendorCorporate  model